SwiftUI Preview SwiftData Initialization Order
I’m trying to get the SwiftUI preview to work for my HomeView, but I’m running into issues with how SwiftData initializes in previews versus on a simulator or device.
In my HomeView, I check if the user’s profile is completed by accessing a SwiftData model. If no profile record is found, I pop up a sheet to prompt the user to fill in the profile information. This works perfectly on both the simulator and actual devices. However, in the preview, the sheet always appears, even if I mock the user data, because it seems that SwiftData doesn’t load before the view lifecycle checks onAppear.
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct HomeView: View {
    @Bindable var loginManager: LoginManager
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @State var showFillUserProfile: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Welcome to Home!")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
            Text(loginManager.credentials.name)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
            Text(loginManager.credentials.surname)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
            Text(loginManager.credentials.email)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()

            Text("You are logged in.")
                .font(.title)
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            loginManager.checkUserInfoExists() // check if user info exists
        })
        .onAppear(perform: {
            print("val of self.shouldShowFillUserProfile "  + "\(loginManager.shouldShowFillUserProfile)")
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: .constant(loginManager.shouldShowFillUserProfile)) {
            FillUserProfileView(loginManager: loginManager)
        }
    }
}


preview:
#Preview {
    let preview = Preview()
    preview.addUser(user: UserModel.sample) // add user here --------------
    let loginManager = MockLoginManager(context: preview.container.mainContext)
    loginManager.setProfileCompleted(true)
    let appManager = AppManager(mc: preview.container.mainContext)
    loginManager.shouldShowFillUserProfile = false
    
    return MainTabView(loginManager: loginManager)
        .modelContainer(preview.container)
        .environment(appManager)
}


The problem seems to be the order in which preview data is loaded. Since SwiftData only loads after the view is initialized, the onAppear check doesn’t find the user data, and thus the sheet always appears.
any solution?

.sheet(isPresented: .constant(loginManager.shouldShowFillUserProfile)), using .constant in your view code looks wrong to me. .constant should only be used in previews as I understand it.

apologies I fix that with $loginManager.shouldShowFillUserProfile but still have the issue on the preview

Please show a [mre] - something I can copy and paste into a new project and reproduce the issue.
